# Mysql index usage issues

Tags: mysql

Mysql is installed based on docker, the specific version is MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.25-1debian10

- Table Structure

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `test_index` (
      `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `my_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID',
      `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
  ```
- Table Data

  ```
  select * from test_index;
  +----+-------+-----------+
  | id | my_id | name      |
  +----+-------+-----------+
  |  1 | 1     | test name |
  +----+-------+-----------+
  ```
- Question statements
  Please pay attention to the execution result of explain: `possible_keys` and `key`。

  For the `my_id` column in `test_index`, there is no index, why it is used as a condition in the update statement, which uses the PRIMARY index?

  Out of confusion, I did execute the delete statement operation with the same conditions, and the result of the execution was the same as I initially expected, without using any indexes.

  What is the underlying rationale for using indexes differently for statements with the same conditions or why they are used? Looking for your help, thanks!

  - Modify statement

    ```
    explain update test_index set name="update name" where my_id=1;
    +----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
    | id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
    +----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
    |  1 | UPDATE      | test_index | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
    +----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
    ```
  - Delete statement

    ```
    explain delete from test_index where my_id=1;
    +----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
    | id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
    +----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
    |  1 | DELETE      | test_index | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
    +----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
    ```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it could have been different. And it might depend on the number of records.

- **UPDATE**: no suitable index found, using the primary index.

  No need to use the primary key's index, but the index is available anyhow.
  May work better when the table is modified concurrently.
- **DELETE**: no suitable index found, not using any index.

  Here the primary key's index is changed, maybe several records with the same `my_id` are deleted. So instead of doing the index change piecewise, it  is better rebuild the primary key's index once.

Comment: @Akina thanks, that is what I meant; I'll change "loaded" to "available."

Comment: First of all, thank you. * UPDATE: no suitable index found, using the primary index. * DELETE: no suitable index found, not using any index. Is the above description for all cases of MySQL? After adding some data to the table, I tried the above operation again and the situation is the same. I also executed the query and the result was the same as the deletion, whether the query also follows the same guidelines as the deletion

Comment: An update might be better safe-guarded against concurrency, hence using an index. A query does not need that. But I agree, we are trying to find logic, where it just might have been two different programmers. ;)